# Converting rectangular coordinates to cylindrical coordinates and then integrating

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int_0^2 \int_9^\sqrt{2x-x^2} (xy) \ dy\ dx$$ 
I have to solve this problem by converting from rectangular coordinates to cylindrical coordinates then integrate it.

I know that $$\ r^2 = x^2 + y^2 $$
 $$\ x = rcos(θ) $$  $$\ y = rsin(θ) $$

I just am confused on what to do next. Does the integral change to:

$$\int_0^2 \int_9^\sqrt{2x-x^2} (rcos(θ)rsin(θ)) \ dr\ dθ$$ ?

Comment: Cylindrical coordinates are for three dimensions. You seem to need some kind of polar coordinates. Are you sure that the the lower limit of the inner integral is supposed to be $9$? It would make much more sense if it were $0$.

Comment: Yes, my professor gave us this problem for homework where 9 was the lower limit of the inner integral and I was a little confused too.

Comment: Especially since $\sqrt{2x-x^2}<9$ throughout the outer integral. It seems almost certain to be a typographical error.

Comment: So we have $9 \le y \le \sqrt{2x-x^2}$ and $0 \le x \le 2$...Well let's look at the $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ This is a top half of a circle with center (1,0) and radius 1. I can show you so square both sides...$y^2=2x-x^2$ Then we have $x^2-2x+y^2=0$. When we add one to both sides we can then write $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ Now the any y value obtained from this $(x-1)^2+y^2=1$ is actually less than 9...So I would probably do this before going to polar coordinates...$-\int_0^2 \int_\sqrt{2x-x^2}^9 (xy) \ dy\ dx$ I'm stuck here.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding what r and theta should be between. I think theta should between 0 and pi/2 since we are in the first quadrant...but I don't know how to get r's range.

Comment: Buy anywho I think you are missing a factor of $r$ in your integrand.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping, I think my professor may have a typo I will try to figure this out after he responds.

Answer (score 1):

It is not suitable to sovle it by your method. Just do it dicretly.

$$\int_0^2 \int_9^\sqrt{2x-x^2} (xy) \ dy\ dx = \int_0^2 x \int_9^\sqrt{2x-x^2} y\ dy\ dx
$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I have to solve it by changing the rectangular coordinates to cylindrical units :(

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $y = \sqrt{2x-x^2}$ looks like this:

[image]

So one thing to do is to find the formula $r = f(\theta)$
that produces the same shape in polar coordinates.
This will tell you what to put as one end of the integral over $r$.

What you put as the other end of the integral depends on how much you
trust your professor's proofreading skills.
If he really, really meant the $9$ in
$$\int_0^2 \int_9^\sqrt{2x-x^2} (xy) \,dy\,dx,$$
then you're really being asked to find
$$-\int_0^2 \int_\sqrt{2x-x^2}^9 (xy) \,dy\,dx,$$
and the region to integrate over is the (mostly) rectangular figure
bounded by $x=0$ on the left, $x=2$ on the right,
$y=9$ on top, and this semicircle on the bottom.

You can do the whole thing in polar coordinates, but it's really ugly:
you need to break it into two parts, one for $0\leq \theta\leq \arctan \frac92$
(covering everything under the radial line that passes through
the upper right corner of your region, $(2,9)$)
and a second part for $\arctan \frac92 \leq \theta\leq \frac\pi2.$
On the first integral $r$ runs from a point on the semicircle to a point
on the line $x=2$;
on the second integral $r$ runs from a point on the semicircle to a point
on the line $y=9$.
That is, you're being asked to integrate a rectangle in polar coordinates,
while taking a semicircular chunk out of the bottom.

Alternatively, you can do the integral $\int_0^2 \int_0^9 xy\;dx\,dy$
in rectangular coordinates, then subtract the integral of
$\int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{2x-x^2} xy \;dy\,dx,$
that is, you remove the semicircle from the bottom of the rectangle.
The integral $\int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{2x-x^2} xy \;dy\,dx,$
looks fairly reasonable to approach in polar coordinates;
at each value of $\theta$, $r$ ranges from $0$ to the 
value of $r$ on the semicircle.

If it was just a typo then you just need to do the integral
$\int_0^2 \int_0^\sqrt{2x-x^2} xy \;dy\,dx$
in polar coordinates.
A handy fact to remember is that the graph of $r = \cos\theta$
in polar coordinates is a circle of diameter $1$ passing through the origin;
by taking $r = 2\cos\theta$ you double the size of that circle and it
now coincides with your desired semicircle.
Just remember to integrate over a large enough range of $\theta$
so that you reach every point on the semicircle, but no farther.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\cos(\Theta)} rsin(\Theta) rcos(\Theta)\ r \ dr  d\Theta$$
this is how you would do it basically